# How to increase log level of Node.js app on Docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp, docker-compose, gulp-task

I already have AngularJS - Node.js app running localy and I can see logs of all levels on my browser after write in my code: **console.log/info/error**.

After dockerize my app and run docker image (docker-compose up), on my browser console I can see only **console.info** logs.

**Question**: How to  achive all levels of logs (i need console.log the most) in my browser using app inside docker image?

Comment: was is the base image you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong - one of my colleague added gulp task to select only INFO logs on production:

```
gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
return ngConstant({
    name: 'myApp',
    constants: {
        VERSION: config.version,
        DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: false  << this flag must be true
    },
    template: config.constantTemplate,
    stream: true
})
    .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});
```